# iPhone iOS how to generate multi page report from a tracker like app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, pdf-generation, reporting

I'm working on an a a calorie counter-like app. The user can report events and track them day to day.. One of the requirements for this app is that the user can generate a multi-page report of the tracked events.

**I'm looking for a report generation framework for iPhone. Is there such a thing?**

I tried creating an 850x1100 template, adding all the required text labels, a tableview and a Core Plot graph there, and converted that to picture>PDF. This approach got rejected, because the customer wants a fully searchable PDF. The complexity involved in this process is too much for me to handle. **Is there a simpler way to generate reports on iPhone?**

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking for services you can call to offload the work / complexity if being connected to the net is aok for your app.  [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) is one such tool cheap but not free -  you can call it from iOS and ask it to render PDFs and other formats - the layout is controlled by templates you upload separately via the website - so you just have to send data.   You'll have to ask if it provides the searchability features you are after.